# Skip extracting value if text node not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am scraping all opening odds from [this page](https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/russia/premier-league-2019-2020/results/)
But I want to skip all canceled events (like on [this page](https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/russia/premier-league-2019-2020/krylya-sovetov-samara-pfc-sochi/2XtfA7VP/)) and print blank result as below:

```
try:
    xpath = '//table[starts-with(@id,"aodds")]//tr[th="Opening odds"]/following-sibling::tr/td[@class="bold"]'
except:
    print('')
    homeodd = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to update your code as

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

xpath = '//table[starts-with(@id,"aodds")]//tr[th="Opening odds"]/following-sibling::tr/td[@class="bold"]'

try:
    homeodd = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text
except NoSuchElementException:
    print('No bets found')
```